# Sharepoint Foundation 2013 Installation on Windows 10

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, installation

Is it possible to install Sharepoint 2013 Foundation on Windows 10.?

I search a lot on google and no where I found trick. I cannot install it on Hyper-V/VM as I don't have windows Server 2008.

I checked this link that suggest tricks to install Sharepoint 2010 on Windows 7. 
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/373724/SharePoint-Installation-on-Windows

But no tricks found for Sharepoint 2013 Foundation.

Comment: In addition to Rob's answer i would like to add that if your computer is capable, you could set up a virtual server using VMWare or Hyper-V and install SharePoint there, but you still need an AD.

Answer (score 3):

SharePoint 2013 cannot be installed on a client operation system. It can only be installed on the 64-bit edition of Windows Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 (SP1) Standard, Enterprise, or Datacenter or the 64-bit edition of Windows Server 2012 Standard or Datacenter.

See [Hardware and software requirements for SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc262485.aspx#section4)

Comment: Any how installed Visual Studio 2013 can use Sharepoint Foundation 2013 APIs. So that we can develop Custom webparts without sharepoint installation on Windows 10.

Comment: There are two types of web parts now. The first type are Classic Web Parts which have been around since SharePoint 2007. You build these using Visual Studio and the Server Object Model. You **must** have SharePoint installed on your development machine to build Classic Web Parts. The second type are Client Web Parts which are new and can only be used with SharePoint Online. These are built using tools like Node, TypeScript and The SharePoint Framework. You do not need to have SharePoint installed on your development machine to build Client Web Parts.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I will try to create Client Web Parts. This is new for me, can you suggest some good step by step learning resource for this.

Comment: https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview